# Jquery: form string var using if

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use statement 'if' in var?

What I want to do is to form one string var from a few dynamic string vars, and if dynamic var is empty - I don't want to include it into final var.
Something like that:

```
var formtext = 
                $('#translit-docs-output').val() + ',' +
                if (docs != '') {return docs+='. '} +
                if (addDocs != '') {return addDocs+='. '} +
                if (conDocs != '') {return conDocs+='. '} +
                $('#translit-dos-output').val();
```

But console will give the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Is there any other ways to achieve such functionality?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sefaw2s1/

Comment: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
var formtext = $('#translit-docs-output').val();

if (docs != '') {formtext += ',' + docs + '. ';}
if (addDocs != '') {formtext += addDocs + '. ';}
if (conDocs != '') {formtext += conDocs + '. ';}

formtext += $('#translit-dos-output').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operator(Ternary) instead of `if` statement

Syntax:

```
  Condition ? If true : If false;
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake.i updated my answer.By mistake i typed consitional statement instead of conditional operator